# Sonar plugin, how to define plugin language

Tags: java, plugins, sonarqube

I'm developing a sonar plugin to analyse TrueScript code using tslint.

My plugin works when I run Javascript project (sonar-project.properties configuration file contains line: sonar.language=js). Because of I develop plugin for TrueScript I want to declare, that my plugin works with TrueScript (sonar.language=ts). When I ran sonar-runner with this configuration file I received message "ERROR: Caused by: You must install a plugin that supports the language key 'ts'".

I defined class TypeScriptLanguage extends AbstractLanguage and added it to list of plugin extensions (class ExamplePlugin extends SonarPlugin has method getExtensions() and I put this TypeScriptLanguage.class to returned list).

What else should I do to "show" that my plugin is for TrueScrypt language?

Comment: A Quality profile should also be created for this language.

Comment: @SimonBrandhof Thank you. Creating quality profile for TypeScript in sonar webpage solved this error.